# Subtracting the values assigned to a same product to get the actual availability

Tags: excel

[Sample Data List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4WI4.jpg)

Hi,

I am currently trying to create an excel file to plan the production of parts based on the availability of stock. I am almost through with the creation of the excel sheet except for one thing which I could not manage to do it with the excel commands like VLOOKUP and INDEX.

I have a worksheet with the partnumbers in column A, required quantity by customer in column B and parts already on stock in column C. Since the required quantity changes with the different delivery dates, I have sorted the sheet based on the Delivery Date. So the part numbers will repeat in the sheet more than one time. The required quantity will also differ. The problem is with the quantity of stock. In case if 2 units of the partnumber 'A123' is required by the customer today and 3 units by next week, we already have 3 units on stock today. So when the 2 units are delivered today then the quantity of stock should be calculated as 3-2=1, showing the actual availability in the column C against the delivery required for next week, which will be used by us to plan our production schedule. How can I calculate this stock availability? Please refer to the attached image for an idea.
Thank you very much in advance for any valuable suggestion on this.

Best Regards,
Aswin

Comment: How to you identify today and next week based on this data?

Comment: Dear Gowtham Shiva, Please find the newly attached sample picture now. I hope that will solve your doubt. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please paste the below formula in cell C5,

```
=SUM(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:A4=A5),$C$1:C4)-LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:A4=A5),$B$1:B4))
```

and drag it till the end. The formula searches for the part number in the reverse order to gather previous week data. Once the part number is found, the quantity is calculated. Let me know if you you need more info. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much Gowtham Shiva!! Works like a charm:)

Comment: Your welcome. You could add conditional formatting for column C in case if the values are < 0, that gives you a heads up that you are running out of stock. Kindly upvote if you found this answer useful. Thanks !!

Comment: That's a good idea. I will certainly do that. And I have already upvoted your  comment but it doesn't show upvotes given by people who have less than 15 reputation as in my case. It's registered anyway. Thank you so much for the help.